# Why is this not calculating total size of the folder correctly?

Tags: java

Here are the two java classes:

```
package je3.io;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by IDEA on 31/01/15.
 */
public class DirWalker {
    private List<File> recursiveList = new ArrayList<File>();

    public void walkDir(String pathname) {
        File d = new File(pathname);
        recursiveList.add(d);
        if(d.isDirectory()) {
            for(String f : d.list()) {
                walkDir(f);
            }
        }
    }

    public void reset() {
        recursiveList.clear();
    }

    public List<File> getRecursiveList() {
        return recursiveList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DirWalker dirWalker = new DirWalker();
        dirWalker.walkDir("/tmp");
        dirWalker.getRecursiveList().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

---

```
package je3.io;

import java.io.File;

/**
 * Created by IDEA on 31/01/15.
 */
public class DirSummariser {
    private DirWalker dirWalker = new DirWalker();
    private long dirSize = 0;

    public DirSummariser(String pathname) {
        dirWalker.reset();
        dirWalker.walkDir(pathname);
    }

    public DirSummariser(File file) {
        this(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    public long calculateDirSize() {
        for(File f : dirWalker.getRecursiveList()) {
            dirSize += f.length();
        }
        return dirSize;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DirSummariser dirSummariser = new DirSummariser("/Users/hualin/Downloads/pdf");
        System.out.println(dirSummariser.calculateDirSize());
    }
}
```

In the main method of the second class, I was trying to calculate the total size of the pdf folder, which should be around 30MB. The java program compiles without error, but says the size of the folder is only 1600 bytes.

Comment: Aren't you using Java 7+? If yes there's a much better way of doing that

Comment: Yes, I am using java 8, but this is sort of an exercise. :-)

Comment: Well, with Java 8 it's much more simple; look at my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in `DirWalker`:

```
public void walkDir(String pathname) {
    File d = new File(pathname);
    recursiveList.add(d);
    if(d.isDirectory()) {
        for(String f : d.list()) {  // <-- here
            walkDir(f);             // <--
        }
    }
}
```

The strings returned by `d.list()` are just the file names, without a path attached to them. If you find, for example, a file `some_directory/foo.txt`, the string you'll pull out of the list is `foo.txt`, and since `foo.txt` is not in the current working directory, the `File` object you construct from it will be invalid (or describe a different file).

You'll have to make the path you're trying to inspect part of the recursion to make this work properly, for example like this:

```
            walkDir(pathname + File.separator + f);
```

Or, as @Adam mentions in the comments, by passing the `File` object that describes the parent directory into the recursion and using the `File(parent, child)` constructor, as in

```
// new parameter here: parent directory
public void walkDir(String pathname, File parent) {
  System.out.println(pathname);

  File d = new File(parent, pathname); // <-- File constructor with parent
  recursiveList.add(d);
  if(d.isDirectory()) {
    for(String f : d.list()) {
      walkDir(f, d);                   // passing parent here
    }
  }
}

// entry point, to keep old interface.
public void walkDir(String pathname) {
  walkDir(pathname, null);
}
```

**Note:** This answer, I think this should be mentioned, is rather tailored to OP's use case of an exercise, so I mainly tried to explain why his code didn't work and suggested ways to make it work. If you're a stray visitor in the future and looking for ways to walk through a directory with Java, look at @fge's answer for a better way.

Comment: @Adam I suppose so, yes. I'll put that in there.

Answer (score 2):

Use the java.nio.file API, it's much better at doing things like this.

Here is an example, also using [throwing-lambdas](https://github.com/fge/throwing-lambdas), calculating the total size of all files in a directory, recursively:

```
final Path theDirectory = Paths.get("path/to/your/directory");

final long totalSize = Files.walk(theDirectory)
    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
    .mapToLong(Functions.rethrow(Files::size))
    .sum();
```

If you don't have Java 8, use `Files.walkFileTree()`.